# Problems turning on weblogic fast-swap to Weblogic 10.3.0.0

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, maven-2, weblogic

I added

```
 <fast-swap>
       <enabled>true</enabled>
   </fast-swap>
```

to weblogic.xml inside the WEB-INF folder in my exploded war to enable hot deployment. then After starting the server, I can no longer set breakpoints in the code ( they are not activated ) to be able to debug.

I also started getting NullPointerException while i don't get it when I turn it off.

```
NullPointerException at com.xyz.MyController_beaVersion0_20.getSessionData()
```

Did you notice the _beaVersion0_20 in the class name?

any idea what additional configuration needs to be done to turn on fast-swap?

I m using eclipse Indigo with OEEP plugin and maven2

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add it in the weblogic-application.xml ?
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13702/deployunits.htm#DEPGD156

Mathieu.

Comment: Thans for your replay. I m using exploded war, so I can't use weblogic-application.xml as it is at the ear level.